# React: How to check the type of a child in the parent's render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that during render I can get the child through refs and, for example, call a function on the child (which I can add to the child for this purpose) to determine the type of the child.

```
<Child ref={(child) => {this._childType = child.myFunctionToGetTheType();}} />
```

But in this example the function isn't actually called until the Child is mounted, so after the `render` of the Parent has finished executing.

I have a parent component that receives its children through props. Because of [React limitations](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127) I need to treat a specific child in a special way BEFORE the `render` of the parent has finished executing (i.e. return something else from the parent's `render` function for that specific child).

Is it possible to determine the type of the child before returning from the parent's `render` function (i.e. without using refs)?

Comment: I cannot stand still not asking "Why you want it?!" :) Looks like bad design

Comment: Even if it's bad design, question still can be asked :) I already stated why I need this. It's a workaround for the React limitation, which hopefully will be addressed in the next release. I essentially need to replace this https://github.com/yoonka/unigrid/blob/8e4c1f1cda4e261691f8ede921a0124fc76ff7bb/src/Unigrid.js#L197 which is used to determine how to render a child here https://github.com/yoonka/unigrid/blob/8e4c1f1cda4e261691f8ede921a0124fc76ff7bb/src/Unigrid.js#L175 with a better solution because the current one doesn't use the official React API.

Comment: Duno why you think it is not a React way, but I think that getting child by ref in the middle of render is more not-react-way then getting type of created (but not rendered) child.

Comment: I don't know if it's React way, I only stated that's not the official Rect API because it gets stripped in production code after minification. And that's because names of React classes gets replaced with shorter names and `elem.type.name` is no longer valid. However, I have noticed that it doesn't strip static function so I might have a workaround in the end.

Comment: spicyj recommends to compare the type to the object exactly - see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4915#issuecomment-162730765. I do not like this, I prefere displayName, but I do not know the way to save it at prod.

Comment: Thanks, will need to verify if comparing child.type with the object will work for me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same issue, where I was relying on `child.type.name` to determine the type of component. While this works fine for me, the issue is that older browsers somehow do not support that so I had to find another way. I was using Stateless Functional Components and did not want to switch away, so ended up exploiting props

```
const MySFC = () => {
  //...
  return (
    <div className="MySFC"></div>
  );
};

MySFC.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string
};

MySFC.defaultProps = {
  type: "MySFC"
}

export default MySFC;
```

then instead of using `child.type.name === 'MySFC'` I used `child.props.type === 'MySFC'`

not ideal, but works

Answer (score 0):

I have added a static function to the class that extends React.Element and it seems that I am able to access it through `child.type.theStaticFunction`. That probably still isn't using the React API correctly but at least it works after the code has been minified (`child.type.name` didn't work because the minifier was replacing class names with shorter versions).

```
export default class MyType extends React.Component {
  static isMyType() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

then when processing the children in `render`

```
static _isChildOfMyType(child) {
  const isMyType = child.type && child.type.isMyType && elem.type.isMyType();
  return !!isMyType;
}
```